# Do I need to grant location permissions to access historical Google Fit distance/miles data on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions, google-fit, google-fit-api

I am building a React Native application and would like to use Google Fit's distance data to get users' data historically for their miles travelled every day after signing in with their Google account. I am currently using the library [react-native-google-fit](https://github.com/StasDoskalenko/react-native-google-fit#readme). However, when using the Google Fit Android API it happens to require Location permissions ([ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization)) to access the distance data and I would like to avoid asking users for location permissions since I don't want to record live location/distance data within my app, just access historical data for their miles. Is there any way to accomplish this via the Google Fit Rest API to avoid asking for permissions instead or would I have to use the Google Android API?

I can't seem to bypass permssions, once enabled the library and Google Fit access works fine but I don't need to record live distance information, just historical, so I'm not sure how to do that using the current Google Fit API.